# Windows 10 Taskbar Icons Blinking (Compressing)

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

Windows 10 Taskbar Icons Blinking (Compressing)

Symptoms:
The right-most icon on the Taskbar appears to compress to the left (as you look at the screen).  The other icons then also bunch to the left.  The frequency is about every 1.5 seconds.  In Device Manager, the screen keeps refreshing.

Registry setting ForegroundFlashCount =1 made no difference.  Neither did setting ForegroundLockTimeout =0 (and rebooting).

What changed?  (Relevance uncertain) The start motor failed and was replaced, whereupon I needed to change the BIOS boot settings from CD to hard disk.

Graphics Card ATi Radeon HD 4600.  No change here, but it doesn’t officially support Windows 10.

Any ideas, any more info needed?

Comment: Run chkdsk and [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Thank you for two good ideas, sadly neither worked.

Comment: They did work, to show that there is nothing wrong with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the ATi Radeon HD 4600 is only supported up until Windows 8.1
([link to Windows drivers](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=ATI%20Radeon%204600)).

The AMD article
[Windows 10 Driver Support for AMD Radeon Graphics Products](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-615)
says this:

> AMD Radeon™ HD 4000 Series products and older are not certified to support Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM) 1.2 or higher and therefore, do not have driver support for Windows® 10.

I don't know of a solution.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of the Radeon HD 4600.  However, the icons behaved for 10 years with that same graphics card. I am leaning towards it being a file corruption, or hardware partial failure.

Comment: What is the actual driver for it?

Comment: I don't know,. Subsequently, the machine won't start.  I have exhausted the troubleshooting options menu.

Comment: Seems like you need a [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: A good suggestion.